# How to hide border behind body?

Tags: html, css, border

As you can see from the image the white `border` is hanging over the green `body`.

[image: SS]

I want the white `border` to hide behind the green `background` so that panels touch the edge of column on both left/right side with no whitespace.

**Code**

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0;
}
.home-panels {
  font-size: 0;
  margin-left: -2.5px;
  margin-right: -2.5px;
  margin-top: 2.5px;
  margin-bottom: 2.5px;
}
.panel-default {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #446CB3;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: 2.5px white solid;
}
.panel-body {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-panels">
  <a href="/inspirations/25-asdf-asdf">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="white-link">asdf asdf</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="/inspirations/4-to-to-to-to-to-to-to-to-to-to-to-to">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="white-link">to to to to to to to to to to to to</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="/inspirations/24-asd">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="white-link">asd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="/inspirations/8-test">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="white-link">test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Give us a sample link?

Comment: Sorry @WorkWe don't know how to do that. Added HTML.

Comment: Whatchu mean, partner? @timmyRS

Comment: hard to tell without a "working" example but I can see on .panel-default this ``border: 2.5px white solid`` ... you could try ``border: 0 2.5px; border-style: solid; border-color: white;`` that would remove the top and bottom borders

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com I think that the border flowing over the green content looks better than the border beeing cut off.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com, I updated my answer. I think you're dealing with a typo. Your body selector should be just `body`, not `.body`.

Comment: sorry I missunderstood the problem then .. I thought you wanted to hide the white borders behind the body! Could you give an image of what you are expecting ?

Comment: Yes I do @j3ff. I want to hide the right/left side behind the body. "that would remove the top and bottom borders", which I don't want to do

Comment: Thanks @timmyRS. You're right it does look good, but in the larger context it doesn't fit right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove extra `margin` from `.home-panels` and it is element `body` not class `.body` in CSS.

and you need to add

```
 .home-panels a:nth-child(odd) .panel-default {
  border-left: 0
}
.home-panels a:nth-child(even) .panel-default {
  border-right: 0
}
```

Note that I added `box-sizing:border-box` to the wildcard selector `*` so it will apply to every selectors.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0;
}
.home-panels {
  font-size: 0;
}
.panel-default {
  border-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #446CB3;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: 2.5px white solid;
}
.home-panels a:nth-child(odd) .panel-default {
  border-left: 0
}
.home-panels a:nth-child(even) .panel-default {
  border-right: 0
}
.panel-body {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-panels">
  <a href="/inspirations/25-asdf-asdf">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="white-link">asdf asdf</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="/inspirations/4-to-to-to-to-to-to-to-to-to-to-to-to">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="white-link">to to to to to to to to to to to to</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="/inspirations/24-asd">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="white-link">test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="/inspirations/8-test">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="white-link">test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: With your code still whitespace. No whitespace should be between panel and body on either side

Comment: What whitespace?? I don't see any whitespace whatsoever

Comment: U have `border: 2.5px white solid;`. That means on all four sides, which means there will be a 2.5 gap of whitespace between body and panel on both sides

Comment: Then if I put `-2.5px` margin left and right side to adjust for it that just puts me back at square one.

Comment: are you telling me that for you `border` is the same as white space ?? because it is not

Comment: Yes that's what I'm telling you and so is wikipedia and wikipedia is always right: "It is the portion of a page left unmarked: margins, gutters, or space between columns. The term arises from graphic design practice, where printing processes generally use white paper. "

Comment: wikipedia it is not always right, don't assume that. But I know what you want now. I'll update my answer

Comment: I was kidding, come on Bart Simpson get with the program. You got it to work. Thanks for your patience buddy :)